# How to upgrade more than 5 computers to windows 8

Tags: windows-8-upgrade

I have several computers running Windows 7 and would like to upgrade to Windows 8, however, the upgrade offer is limited to 5 machines and I need 7 licenses. That is okay with me, I am willing to pay more for the others, but there seems to be no edition available apart from said "upgrade offer". Is there any way to buy upgrade licenses "over the limit", say some boxed retail version?

As far as I can see, those upgrade editions available over the counter do not have that 5 computer limit clause advertised, but it seems rather dumb solution, as the prices is about the same as upgrade offer delivered via download with DVD media ordered as well, which is exactly the same thing.

Any suggestion? Volume licensing does not seem to be an option as it is too expensive.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. I think the question is legit and there isn't any duplicate as far as I know on superuser.

Comment: Oh by the way, the only way to go about this I found to date is probably to buy Windows 8 "Get Genuine Kit", i.e. legalization kit. Which seems just silly.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to link to the specific upgrade offers you're looking at? I've never seen anything that allows you to upgrade 5 computers with one key, so it would be good to see what you're referring to here.